# How to set variables with AJAX request to use in another function in WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

```
$.ajax( {
                method : 'POST',
                dataType : 'json',
                url : my_var.ajaxurl,
                data : {
                    foo : foobar,
                    _wpnonce : my_var.nonce,
                    action : 'my_php_ajax_function'
                }
            } )
            .done(
                function( data ){
                    console.log(data);              
                }
            );
```

wordpress php part:

```
<?php class my_class {
    $yousent = '';
    public function __construct() {
        $this->init_setup();
    }
    function init_setup{     
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_php_ajax_function','my_php_ajax_function' );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_php_ajax_function', 'my_php_ajax_function' );
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue2');
    }
    function my_enqueue2($hook) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script',
            plugins_url( '/js/my-jquery.js', __FILE__ ),
            array('jquery'),
            false,
            true
        );
        $rest_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' );
        wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_var', array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'nonce' => $rest_nonce,
        ));
    }

    function my_php_ajax_function(){
        if ( wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'wp_rest' ) ){
            echo json_encode(
                array(
                    'youSent' => $_POST['foo']
                )
            );
            $this->yousent = $_POST['foo'];
            exit;
        } else {
            echo 'nonce check failed';
            exit;
        }
    }

    function my_another_function (){
//do stuff $this->yousent;
    }
}
?>
```

not working:

```
       $yousent = ""; //data from ajax request
       function my_another_function(){
          echo $this->yousent;
        }
```

how to set `$_POST['foo']` variable into php class variable to use in another function;
`$this->foo = $_POST['foo'];` setting up variable for use in another function seems to be not working

Comment: can you reword what you've written? It doesn't make a lot of sense, and there are no classes in your question so it's unclear what you mean by class variable. Remember that every new request to the server loads WordPress from a blank slate, so you can't set a variable in one request, then use it in another

Comment: i want to set ajax send data add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_php_ajax_function', 'my_php_ajax_function' ); from this function, into a variable which is in the class scope, then i want to use it into another function  my_another_function(){
      echo $this->yousent;
  } which is in the same class scope  is it possible? its give me null value,

Comment: @MuhammadHossain, so `my_php_ajax_function()` and `my_another_function()` are both class methods, i.e. functions in the **same class**? If so, you should call the latter method inside of the main AJAX callback, i.e. do `$this->yousent = $_POST['foo']; $this->my_another_function();` before exiting. Or just pass the POST value to that another function, or just access `$_POST['foo']` from that function.. But all these are actually general PHP/programming which requires no WordPress-specific knowledge.

Comment: $_POST['foo'] is only working on `add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_php_ajax_function', 'my_php_ajax_function' );` registered function my_php_ajax_function, $_POST value only setting up within that function, if i assign that like `$this->foo = $_POST['foo']`  value it is setting up null value , neither i can access $_POST value to any other function only in that registered function, i need to use that value outside of that wordpress registered function..

Comment: if i echo `$_POST['foo']` variable within that registered function `my_php_ajax_function` ajax is giving me success response that means everything is working, it is just not letting me take that $_post['foo'] variable outside of this function, i need to store it in that class variable so that i can access it whenever i needed

Comment: Are you sure those are functions in a class as in `class Example { function A() {} function B() {} }` where `$this` would point to `$Example` as in `$Example = new Example;` ? But even if they're not class methods, superglobals like `$_POST` are available anywhere on the same page of the same PHP script execution, or simply put, in the same AJAX/HTTP request. And as Tom said - PHP always starts fresh from the beginning and no variables are persisted, unless explicitly made so.

Comment: And BTW, please tag the users you're replying to so that they get notified of your replies.

Comment: @SallyCJ yes registered function and another function all are same class function, it is just ajax value which is not taking that value outside of wordpress registered function `add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_php_ajax_function', 'my_php_ajax_function' );`

Comment: Well, if you want to be able to retrieve the submitted data from your another function or elsewhere in WordPress, regardless when, then you can make the data persistent, e.g. by storing it in the database as an option. You could also use a cookie or save to a text file, but the decision is up to you since we don't know what `foo` is - i.e. whether it's a plugin setting, a user data, a post meta, etc.

Comment: @MuhammadHossain can you update your code to include the class? I'm seeing no classes in your question but you are referring to class functions I cannot see, and it's confusing. Instead of describing the code, show it to us, and avoid hiding things or making them abstract/generic, that is also confusing

Comment: @TomJNowell i updated my code now

Comment: You should not be putting functions inside other functions, `my_enqueue2` should not be inside `init_setup`

Comment: @MuhammadHossain I noticed you've used the *action* for the [REST API's authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) nonce, i.e. `wp_rest`, so I was just wondering if that was intended? And actually, have you considered using the REST API instead? You could have a pretty route like `my-plugin/v1/foo` and the response is also defaults to JSON, and perhaps there's already an [existing/core endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/) you could use.

Comment: @SallyCJ thanks for your suggestion,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues

### Broken Callbacks

You've used:

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_php_ajax_function','my_php_ajax_function' );
```

This is equivalent to:

```
When `wp_ajax_nopriv_my_php_ajax_function` happens
    do: `my_php_ajax_function()`
```

Which is not what you wanted, because that is not a function, and there is no `my_php_ajax_function` function.

You also don't just want it on that class, you want it on that specific instance of that class, afterall how will it know what `$this` is?

`add_action` expects parameter 2 to be a callable, so lets look up the callable that matches a class function:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

```php
// Type 3: Object method call
$obj = new MyClass();
call_user_func(array($obj, 'myCallbackMethod'));
```

So instead of `"function name"` you need to pass `[ $this, "class function name" ]`

### Sharing Data Across Requests

Unlike webapps built with Java and other languages, PHP apps are loaded from scratch each time a request is handled and have a limited lifespan. There is no shared persistent program running in the background.

Everytime your browser talks to your server, be it to load a page, or via javascript, WordPress is loaded from a blank slate. When WordPress has responded, it is destroyed and nothing is preserved.

This means all variables are wiped at the end of every request.

If you want to persist/save those values, you have several options:

- store it in a cookie
- store it in user meta if the user is logged in
- store it in the browser and send it with every request
- store it on a post or page ( best for data specific to a post that affects all users )
- store it in an option or transient ( best for global site level data that affects all users )

Comment: i thought it was my fault but i change it like that few hours ago, but still it is not letting me take ajax variable out of `my_php_ajax_function()` this function, i'm thinking as @sallycj said storing ajax data into database from that `my_php_ajax_function()` then access it from there but isn't it performance downgrading, should i use wordpress set_transient method will it work

Comment: oooh, these are on separate requests, then yeah, you do need to make this change but then you need to store any data you want across different AJAX/page loads in the database

Comment: I've adjusted my answer to mention that and offer suggestions of where things can be stored

Comment: thanks a lot i think this is best answer to my query.